# What is x7f in php?

Tags: php

What is **x7f** and **xff** in php?

Is it hexa or octal values?

EDIT:

It is given in PHP 5.3 manual that, as a regular expression, class name would be expressed as: **[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]***.

can any one help what is the meaning of **\x7f-\xff** in above regular expression?

Comment: When writing octal values, it can't contain numbers greater than 7, since it is octal(=8 in decimal). And can't contain letters at all(since it doesn't have digits greater than 7).
So this contains f, then the guess is hex. Have to confirm by searching more or echo it and see.

Comment: `echo hexdec(x7f); //output decimal value of hex value(x7f) = 127`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [integer page on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), the format of hex in PHP is:

```
hexadecimal : 0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+
```

thus it's hex.

Answer (score 4):

As other stated its `x7f` & `xff` are hexadecimal code which corresponds to [extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) characters that can be added as part of class name in php. [ASCII Codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The `0x` prefix (not just `x`) means hexadecimal, so 0x7f is 127 and 0xff is 255.